# Orange python data mining: TypeError: invalid sequence element at 0

Tags: orange

I am getting the following error when i am loading the pandas dataframe for the associated rule.

> TypeError: invalid sequence element at 0

Following is my code:

```
    rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(df, support=0.3)
    print "%4s %4s  %s" % ("Supp", "Conf", "Rule")
    for r in rules[:5]:
        print "%4.1f %4.1f  %s" % (r.support, r.confidence, r)
```

df only has the numerical values and majorly binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer` doesn't work with pandas DataFrames.

Use [Orange3-Associate](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html) to infer association rules from `list of lists` or `numpy.ndarray` or `scipy.sparse.spmatrix`, all of which a dataframe can easily be converted to.